# React HTML point and click generator

Tags: reactjs, html-generation

I want users to be able to design a simple web page to render their content on a page on my site. Are there any projects (ideally react) out there currently that allow a point and click layout design similar to wordpress and generate html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found the Ory Editor - Seems to fulfil all my requirements. 
https://github.com/ory/editor